# Umbraco 7.5.x developing for custom data

Tags: visual-studio, module, umbraco

In Umbraco 7.5, I want to develop a custom 'module' (or whatever it is called in Umbraco) to maintain a product catalog. Products can have images, categories and attributes. Of course, I could make some document types and templates but I don't want to add products as content items. I need to be able to maintain a list of products in the back-end, and then use those products on content pages.

The umbraco documentation for developers is seriously lacking, and the most important pages are throwing 404 errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If I understand correctly the data is not in Umbraco but instead in another database table? Maybe UIOMatic plugin is something for you. https://github.com/TimGeyssens/UIOMatic

Comment: Thanks Mark. That looks very interesting. If not for the plugin itself, then to study their code! Sections and trees seem to be the magic words.

Comment: Cool! For showing data in the frontend you'll probably want to take a look at route hijacking and custom content finders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not single place to get all those knowledge. Following articles will be helpful to you to getting started.

Extending backoffice:

http://www.enkelmedia.se/blogg/2013/11/22/creating-custom-sections-in-umbraco-7-part-1.aspx

http://www.enkelmedia.se/blogg/2013/11/22/custom-sections-in-umbraco-7-%E2%80%93-part-2-the-views.aspx

https://blogit.create.pt/andresantos/2015/11/16/building-an-umbraco-7-backoffice-extension-part-i/

https://blogit.create.pt/andresantos/2015/11/23/building-an-umbraco-7-backoffice-extension-part-ii/

https://blogit.create.pt/andresantos/2015/11/30/building-an-umbraco-7-backoffice-extension-part-iii/

Using petapoco (ORM):

http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/using-petapoco-with-umbraco-is-pretty-sweet

https://cultiv.nl/blog/using-umbraco-migrations-to-deploy-changes/

https://pynej.blogspot.in/2016/11/guide-to-custom-database-access-in.html

Answer (score 1):

I think Ucommerce is the best to use in your situation and it works great with Umbraco.

Here are few links. Hope it helps!

[Ucommerce Developer Section](http://www.ucommerce.net/en/products/developer/)

[Products Catalog doc](http://docs.ucommerce.net/ucommerce/v7.5/getting-started/catalog-foundation/catalog-library.html)

Comment: I've seen ucommerce but I've already got my own specific set of data models in an ERP system and want to transfer that data to umbraco. Besides that, I just really want to get familiar with umbraco development.